# Can I run only a specific container in detach mode with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running **three containers** consisting of `mongo, express, and react` using `docker-compose`.

While I run them by `docker-compose`, **what I need to watch is only the output of express container**. So I want to run the **mongo container in detach mode**.

I'm aware of there is a command to run docker-compose in detach mode, `docker-compose up -d`
However, what I want to do is not to run whole containers in detach mode, but to run some specific containers in detach mode.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your distributed application in detached mode with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and follow only the logs that you are interested in with

```
docker-compose logs -f express
```

---

This way any dependencies defined in the `docker-compose.yml` e.g. dependencies services have to one other are maintained and containers are started in an appropriate order.

Answer (score 5):

yes you can by using the service name as a parmaeter

```
docker-compose up -d service1
docker-compose up -d service2
docker-compose up service3
```